# UIStackView sizeToFit doesn't work as expected

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, swift-playground, uistackview

I've configured a test playground with a `UITableView` and an instance of `UIStackView` as its header.

The stackView contains 10 `UILabel`s.

**The problem is that after calling `stackView.sizeToFit()` the stackView doesn't resize itself to fit all the labels and its size is zero.**

I have to manually set the size of the `UIStackView` to fix this issue, which defeats the purpose of the `UIStackView`.

Here is the code of the test Xcode Playground, so you could reproduce it in your environment:

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    private lazy var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let s = UIStackView()
        s.axis = .vertical
        for i in 0...10 {
            let l = UILabel()
            l.text = "text \(i)"
            s.addArrangedSubview(l)
        }

        return s
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
        configureTableView()
        configureSearchController()
    }


    private func configureTableView() {
        tableView.tableHeaderView = stackView
        stackView.sizeToFit()
        tableView.tableHeaderView?.sizeToFit() // Doesn't work!!!!!!!
        tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: 9, height: 100)
    }


    private func configureSearchController() {
//        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Choose template",
                                                                   comment: "Choose template")
    }



    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 7
    }


     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

     cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

     return cell
     }

}


let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: TestTableViewController())

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = nc
```

Setting size manually achieves the desired result:

```
private func configureTableView() {
    tableView.tableHeaderView = stackView
    tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: 0, height: 400)
}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Why **the stackView resize itself to fit all the labels and make size is zero.** ?? I mean what extra you are doing for this?

Comment: I don't do anything, this is an observed behavior when you run the code I've provided.

Comment: Please clear, you wanted to show all labels or you wanted to hide some???

Comment: I want all the content inside the UIStackView to be shown in its full size.

Comment: You have to mention tableView height, so that's the issue, for now just try `stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        tbleView.tableHeaderView?.frame.size = stackView.frame.size` If your stackView is in cell then you can use UIAutoDimention but you need to give tableviewheader eight.

Comment: Your answer doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Table header views need a little extra help... This may work for you.

```
private func configureTableView() {
    tableView.tableHeaderView = stackView
    sizeHeaderToFit(tableView: tableView)
}

private func sizeHeaderToFit(tableView: UITableView) {
    if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {
        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        var frame = headerView.frame
        frame.size.height = height
        headerView.frame = frame
        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        headerView.setNeedsLayout()
        headerView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```